# Difference b/w Vuser Group Mode & Percentage Mode in loadrunner?

Tags: loadrunner

As i understand so far, in Percentage mode, we can add multiple loadgens & load is shared equally b/w all the loadgens specified for a particular script. In Vuser Group mode, we can only add one loadgen per script.However, user can add multiple loadgens in %mode and then switch to Vuser group mode & the multiple loadgens will be retained. Then:
1. Why do we need these two different modes and what is the significance of each?
2. Are there are specific advantages of one mode over the other?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your understanding is wrong.

we can add n number of LG's in both % mode and % Vuserload.

only load will be percentage wise in % mode and you can vary the Load percentage for each scripts and at the end it will running the script for n users based on your % distribution

V user mode - you can vary the user load based on user count.

Refer the controller user manual for more info.

Thanks,
-Kantha

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not accurate.You can add multiple loadgens to each script in both Vugroup & Percentage mode.

Here is the difference between Schedule by Options- Group (Vuser mode) and Percentage mode.
**Vuser Group mode**: Each Group runs on it's own schedule according to it's run time settings and number of Vusers assigned to each Group. Within each Group you can add different scripts and assign different numbers of Vusers and select the loadgens for each of the scripts. To do so after creating a group, select the Vuser icon from toolbar, and adjust the Vusers & loadgens.

**Consider the example**: I have one group, Say Group-1 and i have included 2 scripts in this Group-1. I assign loadgen1 to script1 and assign 10 Vusers to it. Assign loadgen2 to script2 and assign 20 vusers to it. When running this scenario as Group, each of these loadgens-loadgen1 & loadgen2 will generate 10 & 20  Vusers for scripts script-1 & script-2 respectively.
so each script is running on its own schedule.

If i change the above scenario to percentage mode, then load distribution will change to percentage mode instead of numbers and load both loadgenerators assigned to Group -1 will generate equal load and will be assigned to both scripts-1 & 2 as below:
script-1 will display 33% Vusers with both loadgen1 & loadgen2 allocated.
script-2 will display the loaddistribution as 66.6% with both loadgens-loadgen1 & loadgen2.

**To answer to when we should use which mode:**
In vuser group mode you basically can achieve running of each of the group with it's own Global schedule settings- Duration, ramp up/ramp down etc. Running by Group also enables you to start one group only after the other finishes.

Please let me know in case that helps or in case you have any follow up questions on same.